# Website performance profiling the reason behind long idle time

Tags: wordpress, performance, core-web-vitals

Following is the performance profile for a Wordpress Woocommerce website. The idle time is beyond my knowledge. I checked the other similar questions on the forum but none had idle time like 1315029 ms. How to find out the reason for such a long idle time.[image]

Comment: What are you tracking exactly? If the page has loaded and you do a performance recording it will only show as "Idle" because nothing is happening.

Comment: I read so even in other answers but not all website show such a long idle time. I wanted to read the actual details of performance frames etc.